# how to show a pop up dialog like this following picture?

Tags: android

i want to make a pop up button like traffic racer games share button. 
this button shows three item when it is pressed like this picture.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VrIz.png . 
Actully this button is like this.    https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFnmg.png  but after pressing it you will see something showing on above image.
If anyone know this answer please help me.
i have searched a lot but i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following library you will get what you want as shown in image https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/raw/master/screenshots/menu.gif

**Library**

Android FLoating Action Button -> check the sample app too

https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) to create a custom drop down popup:

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(customLayout, width, height, true);// Create a custom layout with icons
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(buttonMenu);// Define on your UI a button which will trigger your custom popup
```